# jQuery ajax & PHP - insert data into mysql database

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

So I've been trying to figure out the method of posting form data from a textarea using jQuery's `ajax()` function to a mysql database. Problem is, I don't really understand the theory of doing so.

Say there's a form:

```
<form method="post" action="action.php">
  <textarea name="somecontent" rows="5" cols="30">Some content</textarea>
  <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Post to db using ajax" />
</form>
```

The form points to action.php which processes data, yadayada. In a theoretical sense, how could I manipulate jQuery ajax to post the data rather than directly submitting the form data to action.php?

Edit:
I don't understand how to send the data with ajax.

Comment: Define "directly submitting".

Comment: You mean you want it to update in realtime while typing, or when the button is clicked?
Or is there another reason you need Ajax for?

Comment: What I mean to say is what would using ajax to send the data on submit  look like and how does that work? That's where I'm lost.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to catch the form submit event in javascript, prevent the default action (submitting...) and call your ajax / jQuery submit instead.

```
$("form").submit(function(){
  // do your stuff
  $.post(
    "action.php",
    // add all stuff, see their page
  );

  return false; // prevent the original form action from happening
});
```

See jQuery's [`$.post`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/) or `$.ajax` for more information.

Comment: This I already know, I'm just not understanding how to use ajax to pass the data to the server.

Comment: @Dilwin This is how I read your question, but I'll add a jQuery ajax reference...